Canadian returning to live in Canada after years living abroad
I'm a Canadian citizen and I've been living and working in Europe for a few years now. If I decide to move back to Canada, how will I have to fill out the customs Declaration Card; will I have to declare myself as a Resident (as opposed to a Visitor) if I have not yet officially become a tax resident in Canada having just arrived there? I think ticking off the "Resident" item makes more sense (although I may not even have an established address in Canada at that time), but that's the easier part of my question.
The less clear part is that if I will have to declare myself as a Resident, which date will I need to specify in the "Left Canada on" field: the date I left Canada when I last visited it or the date I left Canada when I last resided there?
